# Jump bypasses variable initialization in switch statement

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, switch-statement

I need an `std:: vector<char>` or an `std:: string` in my switch case for some purpose. So, I wrote the following dummy code to see if it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    int choice = 0;

    do {
        std:: cout << "Enter Choice" << std::endl;
        std:: cin >> choice;

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Hi";
                break;

            case 2:
                std::string str;
                std::cin >> str;
                break;

            case 3: //Compilation error, Cannot jump from switch statement to this case label
                std::cout << "World" << std:: endl;
                break;

            default:
                std:: cout << "Whatever" << std:: endl;
        }

    } while(choice != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, I somewhat got it that `str` is an object of `std:: string` type. So, I am trying to jump through this variable initialization.

Then why a definition of C style string does not cause compilation error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    int choice = 0;

    do {
        std:: cout << "Enter Choice" << std::endl;
        std:: cin >> choice;

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Hi";
                break;

            case 2:
                char str[6];
                std::cin >> str;
                break;

            case 3:
                std::cout << "World" << std:: endl;
                break;

            default:
                std:: cout << "Whatever" << std:: endl;
        }

    } while(choice != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make the first code to work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`char str[6];` is default-initialized. In case of C arrays of simple values with automatic storage duration ("allocated on stack") it means "no initialization at all", so I guess it's not an error.

If you, however, initialize the array like `char str[6] = {}`, it will yield an error.

I suggest you put extra curly braces so `str` is in its own scope and is not visible in further `case` statements:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    int choice = 0;

    do {
        std:: cout << "Enter Choice" << std::endl;
        std:: cin >> choice;

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Hi";
                break;

            case 2: {  // Changed here
                std::string str;
                std::cin >> str;
                break;
            }
            case 3: // `str` is not available here, no compilation error
                std::cout << "World" << std:: endl;
                break;

            default:
                std:: cout << "Whatever" << std:: endl;
        }

    } while(choice != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Where to put brackets is a styling preference.

Comment: `str` can not be used after the close brace of the scope. What is the sense to enter a string and it can not longer be used?

Comment: This is a small example. It is not used in the original code as well. But one can do all the processing needed for `choice == 2` inside the `switch` statement: calling functions, pushing `str` to `vector`s, etc. If you need to access `str` strictly after the switch statement, it's a smell: there are no guarantees that `str` will have a reasonable value after the `switch` in general.

Answer (score 12):

Just create a new block for the variable with an extra pair of braces

```
        case 2:
        { // <-- start new block for str
            std::string str;
            std::cin >> str;
            break;
        } // <-- end of block, str will be destroyed here
```

Comment: What is the sense of having the string only inside the scope? After the close brace, it can not longer be used.

Comment: I assumed that was the intention, otherwise why declare it inside the switch statement?

Comment: I guess it's worth to add a hint that variables should be declared in its most inner scope which just spans the intended life-time at best. In certain cases, it's even useful to add an extra scope for a well-defined life-time of a variable. (E.g. it's recommendable for lock guardians or other occurrences of RAII.)